# How to manipulate verification on "text" in Webdriver by Jasmine JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've already tried a lot of codes but nothing passed the tests.

Usually the test is fail when it tried to read this verification or it receive "false" instead of "true".

**All the script is below:**

```
 describe('LiveSite Portal - Client share a document ', function() {

  it('LiveSite - Home Page', function() {
       liveSiteHome();
    });

  it('LiveSite Portal - Client share a document - Load new document', function() {

    element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions-row']//a[.='Share Document']")).click();
    browser.sleep(2000);

    expect (element(by.xpath("//div[@class='upload-section']/div[1]/div[2]/div")).isPresent()).toBe(true);

    captureScreen("documentForm");
    browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.css("input.file-input.upload-file-input")).sendKeys("C:\\automation\\myDocument.docx");
    browser.sleep(3000);

    var reviewElement = element(by.bind('selectedFiles[0].name')); 
    // expect (reviewElement.getText('myDocument.docx').isPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(reviewElement.getText()).toEqual("myDocument.docx");

    captureScreen("documentLoaded");
    browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.xpath("//div[@class='upload-section']/div[2]/div[2]/textarea")).sendKeys("Hi This is my document.");
    element(by.name("email")).sendKeys("idanvcita@gmail.com");
    element(by.name("first_name")).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);

    //expect(element(by.css("span.welcome-back")).isPresent()).toBe(true);

    captureScreen("documentFormReturenedClient");
    browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.css("input.btn")).click();
    browser.sleep(2000);

    // expect (element(by.linkText("Document Submitted Successfully")).isPresent()).toBe(true);

    captureScreen("documentSubmittedSuccesfully");
    browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions']//a[.='Home']")).click();
    browser.sleep(2000);

    expect (browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.vcita.com/v/');

  });

});
```

This is my last attempt:

```
var reviewElement = element(by.bind('selectedFiles[0].name')); 
expect(reviewElement.getText()).toEqual("myDocument.docx");
```

Is anyone know what is wrong with this?

**The error from Protractor is below:**

```
firefox #1] PID: 10036
[firefox #1] Specs: c:\automation\tests\document.js
[firefox #1]
[firefox #1] Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[firefox #1] LiveSite Portal - Client share a document
[firefox #1]   LiveSite - Home Page - pass
[firefox #1]   LiveSite Portal - Client share a document - Load new document - f
ail
[firefox #1]
[firefox #1]
[firefox #1] Failures:
[firefox #1]
[firefox #1]   1) LiveSite Portal - Client share a document  LiveSite Portal - C
lient share a document - Load new document
[firefox #1]    Message:
[firefox #1]      TypeError: undefined is not a function
[firefox #1]    Stacktrace:
[firefox #1]      TypeError: undefined is not a function
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\document.js
:19:36)
[firefox #1]     at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\id
an\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\l
ib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\
idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver
\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1755:8)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise
.js:2056:12)
[firefox #1]     at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roami
ng\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\ru
n.js:125:21)
[firefox #1]     at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
[firefox #1]     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
[firefox #1] From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45
:37)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData
\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.
3.1.js:1174:17)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.
1.js:2209:31)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.start (C:\Users\idan\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.
1.js:2162:8)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3
.1.js:2503:14)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.
1.js:2209:31)
[firefox #1]     at onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.finish (C:\Users\idan\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.
1.js:2477:5)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2504
:10)==== async task ====
[firefox #1] Error
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\document.js
:7:3)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData
\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.
3.1.js:913:21)
[firefox #1]     at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3
.1.js:898:15)
[firefox #1]     at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
[firefox #1]     at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\document.js:1:63)
[firefox #1]
[firefox #1] Finished in 19.558 seconds
[firefox #1] 2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failure
[firefox #1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `isPresent()` function available on `getText()` of an element.

You probably meant:

```
var reviewElement = element(by.bind('selectedFiles[0].name')); 
expect(reviewElement.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

If you want to verify any text to be present in a element:

```
expect(reviewElement.getText()).toBeTruthy();
```

Or, via a custom [`toBeNonEmptyString()`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) matcher provided by `jasmine-matchers`:

```
expect(reviewElement.getText()).toBeNonEmptyString();
```

Or, if you want to check the text to be equal to smth, use `toEqual()`:

```
expect(reviewElement.getText()).toEqual("My text");
```

Comment: Thanks chief, But I want to verify if the text is present.. :/ @alecxe

Comment: Cool, When I should insert the expected text? inside the function of "getText"? @alecxe

Comment: @IdanE updated, is any of these options smth you are trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
 I want to achieve the last alternative: "expect(reviewElement.getText()).toEqual("My text");"
But I receive an error when I trying to run this. :/
Please see the updated error and my code as well @alecxe

Comment: @IdanE it should be `by.binding` instead of `by.bind`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify the element using some locator. Refer https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/  **Write a Test** section

```
var reviewElement= element(by.xxx()); 

expect (reviewElement.getText('Review your information').isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sakshi, but it doesn't help.
I've updated the code + error.
Please check this out. @Sakshi